# Add Minimum Dimensions Text to Featured Image

Tags: plugin-development, post-thumbnails

I have edited the `post.php` file to add this text to the featured image area in the post admin screen. Just a helpful hint on the minimum dimension sizes for the featured image. I am not enforcing actual image sizes.

```
set_featured_image' => array( __( 'Set featured image (837px x 467px)' ),
    'Set featured image (837px x 467px)' ) )
```

Should I put this in my `functions.php` or create a plugin? And how would I go about either one.

Answer (score 0):

### Post Thumbnail HTML

Content can be added to the post thumbnail box using the `admin_post_thumbnail_html` filter. This code can be added to a theme's `functions.php` or a plugin. If the sizing guidelines are tightly coupled to the theme, I'd probably put it in `functions.php`. If you want this text to be present when switching themes, I'd go with the plugin approach.

```
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'wpse240830_admin_post_thumbnail_html', 10, 3 );
function wpse240830_admin_post_thumbnail_html( $content, $post_id, $thumbnail_id ) {
    $content .= __( 'Set featured image (837px x 467px)', 'your-text-domain' );
    return $content;
}
```

### Creating a plugin

Creating a plugin is pretty straight forward. The Codex article [Writing a Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) and the [Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) are good places to start. In short, you just create a php file in the plugin directory which contains a special header. Put your code in the plugin file, then activate it.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WPSE Plugin
Plugin URI:  https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/
Description: Basic WordPress Plugin Header Comment
Version:     0.0.1
Author:      http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/
Author URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/
License:     GPL2
License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: wpse
Domain Path: /languages
*/

// Exit if accessed directly
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; 
}

// Add plugin code here.
```

Comment: not working with gutenberg because it does not implement that filter, see https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/12742#issuecomment-467187842